# Access parent object inside children passed outside of component in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

I want to build filters for online store. When I change any form control's value (filter), it should call a method of the parent component `FilterGroup`. The problem is that I can't access parent within children's `onChange` attribute.

My code:

```
var FilterGroup = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="filter-group">
                <FilterGroup.Header title={this.props.name} />
                <FilterGroup.Content>
                    {this.props.children}
                </FilterGroup.Content>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// Header of the filter group
FilterGroup.Header = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="filter-group-header">
                <span className="filter-group-title">
                    {this.props.title}
                </span>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// Content of the filter group
FilterGroup.Content = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
          <div className="filter-group-content">{this.props.children}</div>
        );
    }
});

// Array that contain all the filter groups
var filters = [];

// Example of filter group
filters.push(
    <FilterGroup key="type" name="Shirt params">
        <select key="size" className="form-control">
            <option value="s">Small</option>
            <option value="m">Medium</option>
            <option value="l">Large</option>
        </select>
        <select key="color" className="form-control">
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="black">Black</option>
        </select>
    </FilterGroup>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>{filters}</div>,
    document.getElementById('filters')
);
```

I've already read about Flux, but not much because I'm not completely sure it's what I need. If I'm wrong, please correct me or suggest another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give a callback function from the parent element to their children as a Props, an the children can call this when the filter change.

So just give the FilterGroup function as props to the children.